# Media Query not responding to changing browser size on desktop

Tags: css, media-queries

My media query just won't work, can anyone see what I've missed? I've tried adding:

- !important; after media query css declarations
- adding css ancestral specificity to media query css declarations

No luck. I have the meta viewport tag in the header. Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fadeshow-0.1.1.min.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="description" content="abc" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.fadeshow-0.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$('#nav').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('open');
});
});
</script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
```

and the css

```
.container {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1024px;
 font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #1a1a1a;
 line-height: 150%; 

}
.content {
 position: relative;
 padding: 43% 17% 3%;

}

h1 {
 font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 2.5em;
 font-style: italic;
 color: #426432;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 1.3em white, 0px 0px 1.3em white, 0px 0px 1.3em white;
 line-height: 150%;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 margin-left: -15px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px){

.content {
  padding: 43% 5% 3%;

 }

 h1 {
     font-size: 1.65em;
     line-height: 150%;
     margin-bottom: 30px;
 }

 .body {
     font-size: 1em;
     letter-spacing: .01em;
     line-height: 150%;
 }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could suggest that you add the alternate css (default) to another media query of min-width 501px. This however shouldn't be necessary, I have encountered issues with characters being skipped as they had been the wrong format being copied from websites.

What is happening or not happening? Is nothing changing? I've dealt with this before and it's always a strange issue. So here are some thoughts and examples of CSS behavior.

In CSS we have a hierarchy decided both on how you select an element and on its position within your stylesheet. Take for example the following CSS selectors:

```
body .test-parent .test-child {
    color: red;
}
body .test-parent .test-child {
    color: blue;
}
```

The result in this case would return `color: blue;` as the final style as it is the last read declaration for that elements color value.

However if we declare the following:

```
body .test-parent-two .test-child-two {
    color: red;
}
body .test-child-two {
    color: blue;
}
```

Then the final value is `color: red;`. This caught me off guard and it took me a while to notice the pattern and fix.

The problem here lies in the selectors. A more in-depth selector (longer / includes more in-between children) will override any others as can be seen by this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkfmxgxu/1/).

Hope that also helps!

Comment: There was absolutely nothing happening – no change – but I tried your suggestion of making another default query at min-width: 501 and now there's a change at least. It's not the change I want, but something is happening at least.

What seems to occur now is that any styles that should have cascaded (anything that I didn't change in the max-width query) is entirely lost – like there's a break in the link to the stylesheet.

Can you imagine an explanation for that?

Comment: You gave me a place to start – Thanks Leviscus! Once I could see the behaviour of the broken query, I decided rather than trouble shoot why the query wasn't working,  to break out all the queries into their own style sheets and every thing is working as it should now.

Comment: Glad to hear that at least your getting somewhere you wanted to be. I also do not like the idea of work arounds such as this. I've dealt with it before and even had !important added without luck. I do have a suggestion for you though. Try using inspect element in any modern browser and use the css inspectors to give you an idea of what's going on. Sometimes unless you use the exact same selectors in a media query they will not work. I'll update my answer with more information on the subject of CSS hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you provided the full HTML snippet in your post. Nonetheless, maybe try:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    /* your code here */
}
```

Comment: I've added the remaining <head> code if that helps to shed some light on the problem – thanks! I tried taking out "screen and" – no change.